# how use Adobe Times Roman SmallCaps with LaTeX

Tags: fonts, type1

I'm running TeXLive 2011 under Mac OS X and have  How do I go about installing and using the actual Adobe Type 1 (`.pfb`) Times Roman SC (small caps) and Times Roman Bold SC fonts? I have those Type 1 files. (Does `mathptmx` or some other package already include the needed .`tfm`'s? Where would I find the .map file to add? Anything else to do?)

**Update: progress so far.**

Following `fontinstallationguide.pdf`, I did the following:

(1) Renamed the Adobe-distributed `tirsc___.*` to `ptmrc8a.*`, and `tibsc___.*` to `ptmbc8a.*`, where `*` is `pbf`, `pfa`, `pfm`, or `arm`.

(2) Create `.fd`, `.pl`, and `.vpl` files by TeXing the driver file:

```
% ptm-drv.tex   
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
\recordtransforms{ptm-rec.tex}
\latinfamily{ptm}{}
\endrecordtransforms
\bye
```

(3) Compile the `.tmf` and `.vpl` files by using `pltoft` and `vptovf`.

(4) Did *not* yet copy the created files into my local texmf tree (`~/Library/texmf`).

**Problem:** There are overlaps already between system versions of some of these files and the newly-generated versions that would go into the local tree. For example, consider `t1ptm.fd`:

- The local version includes entries `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{sc}{<-> ptmrc8t}{}` and  `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{b}{sc}{<-> ptmbc8t}{}` which already appear in the system version.
- The local version includes entry `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sc}{}` which does *not* appear in the system version.

So what will happen when a LaTeX document is processed that calls for the Times-Roman SC font? Will the local `.fd` override the system `.fd`? (If so, then the additional, essential, entries such as `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{<-> ptmr8t}{}`in the system version won't be read!)

Or, will the entries in both the local version and system version be processed? Will this create any conflicts?  If so, how resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You can consult the Font Installation Guide available at

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf

or

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf

that explains step by step how installing new fonts. The "LaTeX Font Guide"

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fntguide.pdf

will tell you how to integrate the fonts with `mathptmx`.

Comment: fontinstallationguide.pdf doesn't seem to suffice. I have Adobe tirsc___.pfb, tirsc___.pfm, tibsc___.pfb, tibsc___.pfm. I renamed them ptmrc8a.pfb, ptmrc8a.pfm, pfmb8a.pfb, pfmb8a.pfm, respectively. I then tex'ed file ptm-drv.tex:

  `\input fontinst.sty
  \needsfontinstversion{1.926}
  \recordtransforms{ptm-rec.tex}
  \latinfamily{ptm}{}
  \endrecordtransforms
  \bye`

but this creates only .fd files and *no* .pl or .vpl (and ptm-rec.tex is empty). Similarly for pfm-drv.tex. What's wrong? How proceed?

Comment: fontinst uses afm files, not pfms.